# creating unreal engine scenes with a command with different arguments passed

Tags: unreal-engine5

Is it possible to somehow create scenes in unreal engine 5 automatically? That is, there is some kind of template, and when the command is launched, arguments are passed that, for example, change the starting point of the scene.